# Discord bot problem, AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'channel'

Tags: python, discord.py

I cant really explain what all of this does, because ive been kinda learning over time and most of this is older code, however when i tried to make a leveling system it was giving me the error 'AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'channel''

So far, i have figured out that (at least i think) that it is most likely related to this: `client=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") bot = client`

and maybe this: `@client.event async def on_message(message): if message.author == client.user: return print("{} sent a message".format(message.author.name)) if message.content.lower().startswith("!lvl"): msg = "You have {} points!".format(get_points(message.author)) await client.process_commands(client.channel,msg) add_points(message.author, 1)`

but as i said before i really dont know how to fix this.

Here is the code if needed:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import json
#import _sqlite3
#import db_sqlite3
import sqlite3
import asyncio
import urlparse3

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
bot = client
##### START LEVEL COMMAND #####

try:
    with open("users.json") as fp:
        users = json.load(fp)
except Exception:
    users = {}

def save_users():
    with open("users.json", "w+") as fp:
        json.dump(users, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def add_points(user: discord.User, points: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in users:
        users[id] = {}
    users[id]["points"] = users[id].get("points", 0) + points
    print("{} now has {} points".format(user.name, users[id]["points"]))
    save_users()

def get_points(user: discord.User):
    id = user.id
    if id in users:
        return users[id].get("points", 0)
    return 0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    print("{} sent a message".format(message.author.name))
    if message.content.lower().startswith("!lvl"):
        msg = "You have {} points!".format(get_points(message.author))
        await client.process_commands(client.channel,msg)
    add_points(message.author, 1)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.create_dm()
    await member.dm_channel.send(
        f'Hi {member.name}, welcome to Coded Chat, a place for having fun, and playing games!'
    )

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you call `process_commands` with `client.channel` which doesn't exist. It should just be `client.process_command(message)`